# Printing the Exact Webpage on Android using JSOUP

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am working with jsoup latest library and i want to parse a webpage into my android text view, i just want a proper webpage as it is viewable on any web browser to be displayed on my android activity.
I have tried many code like this

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://du.ac.in/index.php?
id=634&back=list").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2").get();
```

Now I have my web page in document , I want it to be displayed on my activity as IT WAS DISPLAYING ON A WEB Browser, how to extract , Simple text and URL(Underlined Links) etc to be displayed on my activity?{IN ORIGINAL FORM?}

Comment: If You don't know the answer kindly don't add make it go negative :/

Comment: You probably want to use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: I dont want to use a webview i just want my app to work like facebook app googleplay app u got it ? or should i elaborate more?